# String contain specific characters

Tags: python

If I have the following:

```
name="paula"

list=["l", "p"]

for x in list:
    print name.count(x)

>>>
1
1
```

Which If I understand correctly, is taking the string: `"paula"` and confirming that it has one `"l"` and one `"p"` character.

But what if I wanted to do this:

```
#**if name has both Letters, l and p, then it is a mouse**

name="paula"

list_1=["l"]
list_2=["p"]
list_3=["l", "p"]

for y in list_3:
    if name.count(y):

   print "%s contains the letters %s and %s. %s is a mouse." % (name,w,x,name)  

#assume w and x are already defined


>>>

paula contains the letters l and p. paula is a mouse.
paula contains the letters l and p. paula is a mouse.
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. I realized that in this code, it would check the string `"paula"` for the letter `"l"`. And then it runs again to see if it contains `"p"`. Thus two outputs instead of one.

I believe the `for` loop probably needs to be discarded.

Any help is appreciated guys!

**@  Two-Bit Alchemist- Reason for 3 lists:**

```
#cat, dog, mouse
#if name contains the letter "L", then it is a cat
#if name contains the Letter "P", then it is a dog
#if Name has both Letters, L and P, then it is a mouse
#if Name has no L or P, then loop the question


name="lily"
name_2="patrick"
name_3="paula"

list_1=["l"]
list_2=["p"]
list_3=["l", "p"]


for w in list_1:
    if name.count(w):
        print "%s contains the letter %s. %s is a cat." %(name,w,name)

for x in list_2:
    if name_2.count(x):
        print "%s contains the letter %s. %s is a dog." %(name_2,x,name_2)

for y in list_3:
    if name_3.count(y):
        print "%s contains the letters %s and %s. %s is a mouse." %(name_3,w,x,name_3)
```

Comment: The bottom half of your question makes no sense and is making the whole thing unclear. Why do you want 3 lists all of a sudden? What is `y`? Assume `w` and `x` are defined _as what_?

Comment: I have edited the OP to clarify

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to use sets.

```
name = 'paula'
seek = 'pl'

if set(seek).issubset(set(name)):
    print "{0} contains the letters '{1}'. {0} is a mouse.".format(name, seek)

>>> paula contains the letters 'pl'. paula is a mouse.
```

Comment: +1, but note that `set(seek).issubset(set(name))` can be reduced to `set(seek).issubset(name)` since `issubset` works with any iterable

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to check whether a list of strings can all be found inside another string?

If so, you could do something like this:

```
list3 = ["l", "p"]
name = "paula"
if all(char in name for char in list3):
    print "{0} is a mouse.".format(name)
```

Essentially, how the code works is that it uses a generator combined with the 'all' operator.

The segment of code `char in name for char in list3` will iterate through each item in `list3` and will report a true or false value whether or not the character exists inside the name. This syntax is called a generator comprehension, which is pretty similar to list comprehensions, which you can learn more about [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/).

In a nutshell, `char in name for char in list3` is doing something similar to the following:

```
temp = []
for char in list3:
    temp.append(char in name)
print temp

>>> [True, True]
```

Next, the `all` function is a builtin that takes a list of bools, and returns `True` only when every element in the list is also `True`.

Taken all together, the expression `all(char in name for char in list3)` will evaluate to `True` only when every character in the list can be found inside `name`.

Comment: If you really need three lists, please don't name them `list1`, `list2`, ... `listN`. Just use a list of lists, or individuate the identifier names.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist  Can you elaborate?

Comment: You are saying I should make the lists more distinguishing?

Comment: I am saying you should never end up in a situation where you have `var1`, `var2`, ... `varN`. You should either switch to a list (`var[0]`, `var[1]`, ... `var[n-1]`) or your variable names should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Use `any()` to check if the contents of the list exist in the string:

```
name = "paula"
list_1 = ["l", "p"]
if any(word in name for word in list_1):
    print 'paula is a mouse'
```